# How to store static file on Google cloud storages using heroku deployment?

Tags: django, heroku, deployment, google-cloud-storage

I used whitenoise to save static files, but now I want to save them to Google cloude storage. So I reset dyno and set it as follows, but the static folder is not created in storage. I'm not sure what I'm missing.

google_credential is working well. The upload file is well stored. The level is also done without problems. However, static files are not generated in GCS.

settings.py configuration

```
if DEBUG is False :

    ALLOWED_HOSTS = ["cineacca.herokuapp.com", 'cineacca.com',]
    GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS = os.environ.get("GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS")
    DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE = "config.custom_storages.UploadStorage"
    STATICFILES_STORAGE = "config.custom_storages.StaticStorage"
    STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles')
    GS_DEFAULT_ACL = "publicReadWrite"
    GS_BUCKET_NAME = "cineacca_bucket"
    GS_PROJECT_ID = os.environ.get("GS_PROJECT_ID")
    MEDIA_URL = "/media/"
    STATIC_URL = "/static/"
    
    django_heroku.settings(locals())
```

custom_storages.py

```
from storages.backends.gcloud import GoogleCloudStorage
from storages.utils import setting  


class StaticStorage(GoogleCloudStorage):

    bucket_name = setting('GS_BUCKET_NAME')
    location = "static/"

class UploadStorage(GoogleCloudStorage):

    bucket_name = setting('GS_BUCKET_NAME')
    location = "uploads/"
```

Comment: did you run `./manage.py collectstatic` and upload the static folder on gcs?

Comment: @Ersain Yes and it works well. I think problem is django_heroku.settings(locals()). It overrides STATIC-ROOT and the other configuration. I tried django_heroku.settings(locals(), staticfiles=False) but It cause defaultCredentialError. (I make credential.json with .profile writing echo ${GOOGLE_CREDENTIALS} > /app/gcp_key.json)

Comment: is the issue  resolved now?

Comment: @DivyaniYadav No, I decided just to store them on Heroku. Actually, this is for loading an image for div which has backgorund-image: url ( it has a problem of CORS) but even if the static files on GCS still do not work.